# filesystem is "read only" even though `mount` lists it as "rw"

Tags: mount, fstab, read-only

I'm not sure what happened, but right now all filesystems (except for / which is on a separate drive) are "read only" even though `mount` lists them as "rw":

```
$ mount
/dev/sda1 on /media/Data type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,user_xattr)
```

But when trying to create a file, I get:

```
$ cd /media/Data/; touch hello
touch: cannot touch `hello': Read-only file system
```

Trying to remount as `rw` leads to an error:

```
$ sudo mount -o remount,rw -t ext4 /dev/sda1 /media/Data
mount: cannot remount block device /dev/sda1 read-write, is write-protected
```

Any suggestions? Could this be a physical problem with the drive?

Answer (score 3):

`mount` reads the content of the file `/etc/mtab`.
Under some circumstances is this file not up to date.

Please double-check this against `/proc/mounts`.

The reason for the message `cannot remount block device /dev/sda1 read-write, is write-protected` may be a hardware write protection, e.g. a switch on the usb-stick.

To investigate your problem, you may investigate the output of `dmesg` shortly after you have tried to mount the partition.

Also a file system check with `fsck` is a valuable approach.

Comment: hmm.. you're right - it lists as `ro`. It's a laptop hard drive (non flash).

So what do I do now?